# Kotlin multiplatform: Accessing build variables in code

Tags: gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project which is an SDK providing functionality for iOS & Android applications.

In our `build.gradle.kts` we have a couple of variables that we would like to access within the common code shared code between iOS and Android.

As an Android developer this is how I would usually do in an Android project:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        buildConfigField "String", "SOME_VARIABLE", '"' + SOME_VARIABLE_IN_GRADLE_FILES + '"'
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And then i could access it in code:

```
val someVariable = BuildConfig.SOME_VARIABLE
```

How would one do to make something similar to work in a Kotlin Mulitplatform project, since `BuildConfig` is not something that is recognised in the common shared code base.

After searching on this topic for a solution I have yet not found any relevant answers, however my googlefoo skills might not be enough...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[The answer provided by @Evgeny](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74755812/4161471) will solve the problem, but I think this is a good example to learn how to solve this problem in pure Gradle. Even if you want to use a plugin, understanding how Gradle works can help with understand how to customise any plugin or Gradle behaviour.

### Generating source code

There's a couple of Gradle utils that can be used to generate code from build properties.

1. [`TextResourceFactory`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.resources.TextResourceFactory.html) can create files dynamically.
2. [Tasks that create output files can be used as inputs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#working_with_task_dependencies_in_lazy_properties) ([example](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies_between_subprojects.html#sec:depending_on_output_of_another_project)).

It's also important to be mindful of [lazy configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html). The file should *only* be generated when it is necessary.

#### BuildConfig generator task

Tasks are how work is defined in Gradle, so let's make a task that will produce a file as output. [`Sync`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Sync.html) is a good task type for this. `Sync` will copy any number of files into a directory.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

val buildConfigGenerator by tasks.registering(Sync::class) {
  // from(...) // no input files yet

  // the target directory
  into(layout.buildDirectory.dir("generated-src/kotlin"))
}
```

If you run `./gradlew buildConfigGenerator` then the task will run, but the only thing that happens is that an empty directory `./build/generated-src/kotlin/` is created. So let's add a file as an input.

#### Defining a generated file

[`TextResouceFactory`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.resources.TextResourceFactory.html) is a little known tool that can create text files dynamically. (Including downloading text files from URLs, which can come in handy!)

Let's create a Kotlin file using it.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

val buildConfigGenerator by tasks.registering(Sync::class) {

  from(
    resources.text.fromString(
      """
        |package my.project
        |
        |object BuildConfig {
        |  const val PROJECT_VERSION = "${project.version}"
        |}
        |
      """.trimMargin()
    )
  ) {
    rename { "BuildConfig.kt" } // set the file name
    into("my/project/") // change the directory to match the package
  }

  into(layout.buildDirectory.dir("generated-src/kotlin/"))
}
```

Note that I had to rename the file (`TextResourceFactory` will generate a random name), and put set the directory to match `package my.project`.

Now if you run `./gradlew buildConfigGenerator` it will actually generate a file!

[image]

```kotlin
// ./build/generated-src/kotlin/BuildConfig.kt

package my.project

object BuildConfig {
  const val PROJECT_VERSION = "0.0.1"
}
```

However, there are two more things to fix.

1. I don't want to run this task manually. How can I make Gradle run it automatically?
2. Gradle doesn't recognise `./build/generated-src/kotlin/` as a source directory.

We can fix both in one go!

#### Linking the task to the source set

You can add new source directories to a Kotlin SourceSet via the Kotlin Multiplatform plugin DSL via [`kotlin.srcDir()`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-dsl-reference.html#source-set-parameters)

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.7.22"
}

kotlin { 
  sourceSets {
    val commonMain by getting {
      kotlin.srcDir(/* add the generate source directory here... */)
    }
  }
}
```

We could hard-code `kotlin.srcDir(layout.buildDirectory.dir("generated-src/kotlin/"))` - but now we haven't told Gradle about our task! We would still have to run it manually.

Fortunately, we can have the best of both worlds. Thanks to Gradle's Provider API, [a task can be converted into a file-provider](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#working_with_task_dependencies_in_lazy_properties).

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

kotlin { 
  sourceSets {
    val commonMain by getting {
      kotlin.srcDir(
        // convert the task to a file-provider
        buildConfigGenerator.map { it.destinationDir }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

(Note that because `buildConfigGenerator` was created using `tasks.registering()` its type is `TaskProvider`, the same won't be true of tasks created using `tasks.creating()`.)

`generatedSourceDirProvider` will lazily provide the generated directory, and because it was [mapped](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Provider.html#map-org.gradle.api.Transformer-) from a task, Gradle knows that it *needs* to run the connected task whenever the `commonMain` source set is used for compilation.

To test this, run `./gradlew clean`. The build directory is gone, including the generated file. Now run `./gradlew assemble` - and Gradle will automatically run `generatedSourceDirProvider`. Magic!

#### Future improvements

##### Generating the source during IDEA sync

It's a bit annoying that the source isn't generated when I first open the project in IntelliJ. I could add the [gradle-idea-ext-plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin), and make IntelliJ trigger `buildConfigGenerator` on a Gradle sync.

##### Dynamic property

In this example, I hard-coded `project.version`. But what if the project version is dynamic?

In this case, we need to use a provider, which can be mapped to a file.

```kotlin
// build.gradle.kts

val buildConfigGenerator by tasks.registering(Sync::class) {

  // create a provider for the project version
  val projectVersionProvider: Provider<String> = provider { project.version.toString() }

  // map the project version into a file
  val buildConfigFileContents: Provider<TextResource> =
    projectVersionProvider.map { version ->
      resources.text.fromString(
        """
          |package my.project
          |
          |object BuildConfig {
          |  const val PROJECT_VERSION = "$version"
          |}
          |
        """.trimMargin()
      )
    }

  // Gradle accepts file providers as Sync inputs
  from(buildConfigFileContents) {
    rename { "BuildConfig.kt" }
    into("my/project/")
  }

  into(layout.buildDirectory.dir("generated-src/kotlin/"))
}
```

###### Dynamic properties

What if you want to generate a file from multiple properties? In this case, I would either

- [create a custom task type](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_tasks.html), with a named [input property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_inputs_outputs) for each property I want to use to generate the file
- or use a [`MapProperty`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#working_with_maps), set all properties into it, and then (because `MapProperty` is a Gradle provider) [`.map { }`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/Provider.html#map-org.gradle.api.Transformer-) the [map](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/MapProperty.html) into a file

Comment: Thank you @aSemy, could not have asked for a more clear answer. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @aSemy
Your answer helped me a lot.

By the way, I used the `Copy` task because I was concerned about the following statement.

> All files that exist in the destination directory will be deleted before copying files
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Sync.html

Comment: @wrongwrong Typically I'd recommend using Sync over Copy, because if the name of a file changes then Copy won't clean up the destination directory, meaning the destination is dirty, while Sync will remove outdated files. However, if you're certain the file name will never change, or you want to confirm the behaviour first then Copy is an alternative.

Comment: I was looking for such a good gradle guide. I implemented it but I got error `Parameter specified as non-null is null: method org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.NamedDomainObjectCollectionExtensionsKt.getValue, parameter <this>` when added for call and import.

Comment: Ok! I found the answer. I placed the task at the end of file. But when I moved it to the before of `kotlin` invocation, all worked correctly

Answer (score 6):

You can use `com.github.gmazzo.buildconfig` gradle plugin for that purpose ([github](https://github.com/gmazzo/gradle-buildconfig-plugin)).

You can find sample for KMM project [inside](https://github.com/gmazzo/gradle-buildconfig-plugin/tree/master/example-kts-multiplatform).

Basically you should add:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    // other plugins
    id("com.github.gmazzo.buildconfig") version "<latest>"
}

// ...

buildConfig {
    // common config
    buildConfigField("String", "COMMON_VALUE", "\"aCommonValue\"")

    // for specific source set
    sourceSets.named<BuildConfigSourceSet>("jvmMain") {
        buildConfigField("String", "PLATFORM", "\"jvm\"")
        buildConfigField("String", "JVM_VALUE", "\"JvmValue\"")
    }
}
```

Also you can take a look at `com.codingfeline.buildkonfig` ([github](https://github.com/yshrsmz/BuildKonfig)) it has similar API

Comment: This is the preferred solution. The BuildKonfig is far too complicated for most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

you can use open source library for making build konfig fields and it's too easy to use
https://github.com/yshrsmz/BuildKonfig

**please make sure when u add library plugin u also must specify the buildKonfig block**

```
import com.codingfeline.buildkonfig.compiler.FieldSpec.Type.STRING

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.0")
        classpath("com.codingfeline.buildkonfig:buildkonfig-gradle-plugin:latest_version")
    }
}

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("com.codingfeline.buildkonfig")
}

kotlin {
    // your target config...
    android()
    iosX64('ios')
}

buildkonfig {
    packageName = "com.example.app"
    // objectName = "YourAwesomeConfig"
    // exposeObjectWithName = "YourAwesomePublicConfig"

    defaultConfigs {
        buildConfigField(STRING, "name", "value")
    }
}
```