# Create a file in resources when building

Tags: gradle, jvm, gradle-kotlin-dsl

This is for a JVM app.

I am creating a properties file with the version to use in the app runtime. I wrote this task in the base project `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
allprojects {
    //...

    tasks.register("createVersionPropertiesFile") {
        group = "build"
        doLast {
            val resourcesDir = File("$buildDir/resources/main").apply { mkdirs() }
            val resource = File(resourcesDir, "version.properties")
            resource.writeText("version=${project.version}")
        }
    }
}
```

If I run this task independently, it creates the file as I expect.

To run the task during the build, I put this in the app module's `build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
tasks.processResources {
    dependsOn += tasks["createVersionPropertiesFile"]
}
```

However, during the build process, the resources directory is actually removed and not created (or if it is, it gets deleted again before the build is complete). So, the resource isn't found when the app runs.

How can I set up this task to run at the appropriate stage of the build process?

I know an alternate strategy would be to create the resource file in the actual resources directory of the source code, but I don't want to dirty the checked in source code with this auto-generated file. I want it to be only a part of the build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `build/resources/` dir is an *output* directory of the `processResources` task, so ([as per the Javadoc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.language.jvm.tasks.ProcessResources.html)) any other files will be removed automatically.

There's a better way to hook up a task so Gradle will recognise it as source file, and make Gradle automatically run the file.

For simplicity I'll demonstrate how to set up `createVersionPropertiesFile` in a single `build.gradle.kts`, without the `allprojects {}` config.

#### Registering task inputs and outputs

First, make sure in your generation task you register an [output directory, as well as the inputs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/incremental_build.html#sec:task_inputs_outputs). This can be done using the [runtime API](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/incremental_build.html#sec:task_input_output_runtime_api). Tasks have a default `tempDirectory` that's perfect for using as an output directory, but you can use a custom directory if you like.

The project version should be set as an input property of the task, so that Gradle knows it needs to re-run the task if the value changes. To be compatible with Gradle's Configuration Cache ([`project` mustn't be used during task execution](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:use_project_during_execution)), it should be defined as a `val` inside the task configuration block.

```kotlin
val createVersionPropertiesFileTask = tasks.register("createVersionPropertiesFile") {
  group = "build"

  // define a local val, to be compatible with Configuration Cache
  val projectVersion = project.version
  // Register the project version as a task input, so Gradle can cache the task
  inputs.property("projectVersion", projectVersion)

  // tell Gradle about the output directory
  outputs.dir(temporaryDir)

  doLast {
    val resource = File(temporaryDir, "version.properties")
    resource.writeText("version=${projectVersion}")
  }
}
```

The docs explain more about why [registering inputs and outputs is beneficial](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/incremental_build.html#sec:task_input_output_side_effects). What's important here is that, thanks to Gradle's Provider API, [a task can be converted into a file-provider](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#working_with_task_dependencies_in_lazy_properties).

#### Task as a file provider

Java projects are organised using [SourceSets](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSet.html). These come preconfigured with the `src/main/java` and `src/test/resources` that we know and love, and it's possible to add more:

```kotlin
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      // add an additional source directory
      srcDir("$buildDir/some-extra-sources/java")
    }
    resources {
      // add an additional resource directory
      srcDir("$buildDir/some-extra-sources/resources")
    }
  }
}
```

While you *could* hardcode the output directory of `createVersionPropertiesFile` to be an additional resource directory, Gradle wouldn't know that it needs to run the task to generate the files. We can have a two-for-one deal: add a new resource directory, *and* tell Gradle it needs to run the task.

```kotlin
sourceSets {
  main {
    resources {
      // add a new resource dir that is produced by the task
      srcDir(createVersionPropertiesFileTask.map { it.temporaryDir })
    }
  }
}
```

Note that there's no need to add any `dependsOn(createVersionPropertiesFileTask)` - so you can remove the configuration for `tasks.processResources`.

Now when you run `./gradlew build`, you'll see your custom file will be generated into `build/resources` by the `processResources` task.

Another little bonus if you're using IntelliJ: it will highlight the new resource directory in the Project explorer sidebar.

#### Configuring the task for all projects

Something you might find problematic is using `allprojects {}` to configure this task for all projects. (There are a [few](https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/sharing_build_logic_between_subprojects.html#sec:convention_plugins_vs_cross_configuration) [other](https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/multi_project_configuration_and_execution.html#sec:decoupled_projects) [reasons](https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/performance.html#only_apply_plugins_where_theyre_needed) why `allprojects {}` and `subprojects {}` are discouraged.)

Instead, consider creating a convention plugin that creates and configures `createVersionPropertiesFileTask` in a few easy steps using [buildSrc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources):

1. create `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` and, since buildSrc is effectively a stand-alone project, `buildSrc/settings.gradle.kts`
2. Apply the [`kotlin-dsl`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin-dsl_plugin) plugin in `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts`, so we can make [pre-compiled script plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins).
3. Create a file for your convention, using the config provided above.

   ```kotlin
   // ./buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/my-java-conventions.gradle.kts

   plugins {
     java
   }

   val createVersionPropertiesFileTask = tasks.register("createVersionPropertiesFile") {
     group = "build"

     val projectVersion = project.version
     inputs.property("projectVersion", projectVersion)

     outputs.dir(temporaryDir)

     doLast {
       val resource = File(temporaryDir, "version.properties")
       resource.writeText("version=${projectVersion}")
     }
   }

   sourceSets {
     main {
       resources {
         srcDir(createVersionPropertiesFileTask.map { it.temporaryDir })
       }
     }
   }
   ```
4. Now, in all subprojects, you can specifically apply the convention plugin where it is required - no more need for `allprojects {}`

   ```kotlin
   // ./app-subproject/build.gradle.kts

   plugins {
     `my-java-conventions`
   }
   ```

#### WriteProperties task

Since you're generating a `.properties` file, you might also want to consider using the built-in task type for generating properties - [WriteProperties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.WriteProperties.html). It has some utilities for adding multiple properties, and making sure the generated file is re-producible (so that Gradle's caching works well.)

#### See also

- [Kotlin multiplatform: Accessing build variables in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74743976/kotlin-multiplatform-accessing-build-variables-in-code)